# php and apache http server installation issue

Tags: php, apache

I have installed `php-5.4.42-Win32-VC9-x86` and `apache_2.4.2-x86-no-ssl.msi` in my PC.

According to this 
[Link](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-PHP-windows-7.php)

I have installed **PHP** and apache server and configured. I have restarted my computer after configuration.

I created a `phpinfo.php` file in the website folder. When i try to run this file in the browser(http://localhost/phpinfo.php) i am getting webpage not available error. But when i run the localhost i am getting as "It Works".

Also when i test the configuration i am getting error as "syntax error on line 172 in `httpd.conf`, cannot load `c:/PHP/php5apache2.2_dll` into server.The specified procedure could not be found."

I resolved the problem of this error by changing phpapache2.2_dll to phpapache2.4.dll. I hadve both of them in my php folder.

My PC has 32 bit OS.I have also specified the path of PHP in environment variable.

But still when i run my file i am getting webpage not available.
Can any one help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Look if the php*.dll is in the folder that is displayed in the errormessage. Maybe it is just misspelled.

Comment: I have phpapache2_2.dll in the folder same as exactly what is in the error message

Comment: make sure where you created phpinfo.php file, it must be in doc root , if you have created another folder then , you must create alias / virtual host configuration.

Comment: I have created a folder called website in c drive and changed the document root to website but still i am getting web page not available